# Timeout for the requested operation has expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, msmq

This is driving me crazy. We use a fairly large number of private MSMQ queues in our C#/ASP.NET web application where I work and have a common library to send and receive messages from our queues. Yesterday, this stopped working for me altogether, but none of the other developers I work with are running into this issue, which makes me think it has something to do with my local dev environment or my Windows account settings.

I am now always getting "Timeout for the requested operation has expired" exceptions when the following line of messaging code is called:

```
var returnMessage = fromMessageQueue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(strCorrelationID, tsWait);
```

We basically have an "Inbound" and "Outbound" queue for each of our (business) clients. The Inbound queues look clean, but when I look in the Outbound queues, I can see "stuck" messages that are the responses I need.

I've even written a small test console application against a dummy queue I setup for troubleshooting, that still returns the same timeout exceptions.

I've checked the permissions on the private queues I've been troubleshooting with, EVERYONE and ANONYMOUS users have full control to the queues. I've even granted my own domain login account to a few queues, but that didn't work either.

I'm afraid I'm very stuck until I can get this resolved.

Comment: how can I reduce the timeout value ?

Answer (score 2):

I usually get this when I have installed the software and have it running as a service whilst trying to run a debug copy through visual studio (2 services running on 1 queue)